# Error After install Custom Module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

I have developed a custom module in magento 2. I have installed the module but getting error like below.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/Magento-CE-2.1.9/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase.php on line 69

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/Magento-CE-2.1.9/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase.php on line 69
```

When I disable the module everything works perfect. Can anyone please let me how can I resolve this. I am using PHP Version 7.0.25 and Magento version 2.1.9

[image]

Comment: if possible then put our module code so  one can check for the issue. 
The issue is somewhere string argument is required and you are passing array over there.

Comment: Could you please provide whole module here so we can debug and then come up with some solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is old, but in my case i had the same problem and reach this issue here .
It was an error in my system.xml payment method file, where i put the  tag on a wrong place.  So this problem can be a system.xml file with wrong configurations.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Wrong tag placement.

Answer (score 0):

My code snippet is from Magento 2.2 and things are more strict in Magento 2. 
Here it states clearly that you need to pass an array when you make an instance of the class.

```
.../framework/Phrase.php:69
public function __construct($text, array $arguments = [])
```

Or maybe you should develop your code in smaller steps.
First use a generator to get a working framework for a module, like:
https://mage2gen.com/
Then add your custom code bit by bit and when it fails, then you know where the error is.